# Prove that the center of a group is nonempty

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Prove that $Z(G)$ (the center of $G$) is always nonempty.

Can anyone give me solution of this theoretical problem? I have just started learning group theory and I am very interested in this math branch

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Think of the neutral element^^

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $e$ be identity element of group $G$ then

$$ex=xe~~~~~~~~\forall x\in G$$

$$\implies e\in Z(G)\implies Z(G)\neq \emptyset$$

Comment: Just a formatting tip, use $\varnothing$ for the empty set ;)

Comment: @Ed_4434 that would seem  more useful as a suggestion  if you'd include the source. // The symbol $\phi$ `$\phi$ ` is not commonly used for the emptyset. Instead one uses $\emptyset$  `$\emptyset$ ` or $\varnothing$  `$\varnothing$` Personally I always use the former, but other prefer the latter.

Comment: It's easy enough to right click and show TeX commands.

Comment: @Ed_4434 I see; good point. But you see, I did not think of that option (though I should have).